# react native rebuild .bin folder in node modules

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, cocoapods, node-modules

Cause of `could not follow symbolic link` error after upgrading react native from 0.59.4 to 0.60.4, i should remove .bin folder.
The problem is solved on android version but in iOS, when i use `pod install` pod says :

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: No such file or directory - ./node_modules/.bin/react-native.

 #  from /path-to-project/ios/Podfile:40
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  
 >    use_native_modules!
 #  end
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

Is there any way to rebuild `.bin` folder?

Could you please help me?

Thanks

Comment: Please check my answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58693560/12320320)

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57812936/11212074

Answer (score 0):

Remove node_modules and reinstall.

`rm -rf node_modules && npm i`